# Tcl - get message in socket buffer

Tags: sockets, tcl

I have created a socket client to connect to a python server.

I check the `tcl` manual script, it said that **"gets"** - gets the line up to the EOL character.

Manual: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/gets.htm

However, the message sent from the python server is without EOL.

Is it possible to get it from the buffer directly?

Answer (score 0):

When working with binary data (i.e. not line-based), the `read` command is usually more suitable than `gets`.

The manual page for the `read` command can be found here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/read.htm

I would also encourage you to use a more current version of Tcl than 8.4, which is over a decade old. The current version is Tcl 8.6.

---

**Update after more details were provided in the comments:**

If the server doesn't indicate the length of the data it sends, doesn't send a newline at the end, and doesn't close the socket, that makes it quite hard for the client.

The usual way to handle that in Tcl is to set the channel to non-blocking and listen for readable events:

```
set fd [socket $server $port]
fconfigure $fd -blocking 0 -buffering line
fileevent $fd readable [list receive $fd]
# Send an initial string to the server
puts $fd Hello!

proc receive {fd} {
    if {[eof $fd]} {
        puts "The server closed the connection"
        close $fd
        exit
    } else {
        set data [read $fd]
        if {$data ne ""} {
            puts "Received: $data"
            # Send a response back to the server
            if {$data eq "Hey guys"} {
                puts $fd "Hey you"
            } else {
                puts $fd "I don't understand $data"
            }
        }
    }
}

# Run the event loop (not necessary when using Tk)
vwait forever
```

By making the channel non-blocking, the `read` command will return all data available at that point in time. The readable event triggers when there is any data available. Simply calling `read` immediately after connecting would probably produce no data at all. So that won't work. The alternative would be to poll every x milliseconds, but that is rather inefficient.

**Note**: Some people may point out that the above receive proc is incorrect because "the check for eof must be done after reading". But those people don't fully grasp event based file processing. If the `read` command encounters the end of the file or stream, the readable event will fire again immediately. The `receive` proc is invoked again and it then handles the end of file condition.

Comment: I'm not sending binary data... On python side, it sends some thing like `connection.sendall('Hello World')`. Thus there is no EOL.

Comment: For the Tcl version, I'm working on a environment that I can't change a lot. There only provides tcl 8.4. I'm struggling with it, too. haha

Comment: I also tried `read` command, but if _numChars_ is over the length of the message, tcl still can't receive it. And in my case, the length of the message from python is undetermined. It could be _Hello World_ or _Hey guys_.

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your comments.

Comment: I still failed to use it. More accurately, I modified it in my application and I failed. 
What I want to do tcl `send` -> python `recv` -> python handle the message -> python `send` -> tcl `recv` -> tcl next `send`, etc. Thus I can't use `vwait forever` because I still have to send other messages.

Comment: I tried to use your `receive` proc to receive data into a global variable, say `$::recvData`, and when I really wanted to receive it (after sending a message), I created a while loop to detect the length of `$::recvData`. If larger than zero, then I stored it. However this method fails. Maybe I understand the triggering mechanism of `fileevent`.

Comment: When messages get over a certain size, usually around 1500 bytes but maybe less (it depends on the connection and *all* the systems in between), they tend to get delivered in several pieces and that can make protocol implementations a bit more complex. For debugging a particular protocol's implementation, it really helps to see the code for both sides so we can predict the actual messages being sent.

Comment: The `vwait forever` command really waits for the variable "forever" to change. While it waits, events are handled. And since variable "forever" is never written, that's actually all that happens. And from your description that seems exactly what you need. I have updated my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

The standard for network connections' end of line is CRLF, which Tcl opens sockets in by default, but the server probably doesn't follow.

Try `fconfigure $mysocket -translation auto` to accept both CR, LF and CRLF.